# Добавление методов доставки Woocommerce не плагином

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

В общем дескрипшн.
Заказчик хочет добавить 2 способа доставки путем добавления двух виджетов и дать юзеру возможность выбирать методы доставки. Речь идет о СДЕК и почте россии. Есть доступа к виджетам, с личными кабинетами и прочим. Использовать платные плагины где все это уже написано - заказчик не хочет.
https://widget.pochta.ru/widgets //-- почта России
https://widget.cdek.ru/ //-- CDEK

Ему надо чтобы в процессе заказа юзер выбирал метод доставки и данные с соответствующего виджета - передавались дальше в сам заказ.
Я поначалу думал решить все через плагины - но бесплатных решений нет. Есть вариант сделать попап с двумя кнопками грубо говоря, что-то типа почта россии и сдек. при клике на кнопку отобразить виджет, затем данные с виджета насильно через джс впихнуть в форму заказа вукомерс. Но это решение мягко говоря плохое. Может подскажете что получше, или может я что не знаю о вукомерс и там все можно из коробки сделать?

Comment: В сети масса инструкций как это сделать, вот, например: https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098

Comment: я видел этот метод, но мне надо использовать те виджеты которые предоставил заказчик.

Comment: Там описано решение, можно сделать виджет и прикрутить это решение к нему.
Если будете искать готовое решение для своей задачи, то не найдете, она слишком специфична.

Comment: Понял, ладно, буду делать так. спасибо